# Add Taxvat field to magento 2 checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout

I'm from Brazil, and here we use the "taxvat" customer field to store a number called "CPF". I managed to make the field appear on checkout by adding it to an layoutProcessor, like this:

```
      $shippingFields['taxvat'] = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
        'label' => __('CPF'),
        'config' => [
            'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
        ],
        'placeholder' => 'CPF *',
        'validation' => [
            'required-entry' => 1
        ],
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'source' => 'customer.taxvat',
        'dataScope' => 'customer.taxvat',
        'sortOrder' => 1,
    ];
```

But, i don't know why, this field it's not saving on database. It only works if i save this field on customer form, not on checkout form.

Anyone know what i'm missing?

thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220388/add-taxvat-field-to-magento-2-checkout-page

Comment: already asked on https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220388/add-taxvat-field-to-magento-2-checkout-page